# DateTimePicker get value from ListView c#

Tags: c#, forms, ado.net, window, datetimepicker

I have a ListView in which there is a column with Date(20.02.2000). 
How do I get this value and put im in DateTimePicker?

```
dateTimePAterizare.Value = DateTime.Parse(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text);
```

It is giving this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Igor, hope you accept more answer as you learn this community.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your date which is in the form of string is not in the proper `DateTime` format. Use **[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)** which allows you to parse it to `date` by supplying the pattern of the the date you want to convert to.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dateTimePAterizare.Value = time;
```

Comment: [**More Examples Here...**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)